# cannot call methods on flipswitch prior to initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-flipswitch

I want to set the selected value of a jQuery Mobile flipswitch:

```
<select id="quote" data-role="flipswitch" data-theme="b">
    <option value="nee">Nee</option>
    <option value="ja">Ja</option>
</select>
```

When doing the following I get an error:

```
 $("#quote").val('nee').flipswitch('refresh');
```

"cannot call methods on flipswitch prior to initialization"

I have also tried:

```
$("#quote").val('nee').slider().flipswitch('refresh');
$("#quote").val('nee').flipswitch().flipswitch('refresh');
```

How can I get this right?

Comment: With jQM you dont use document.ready(). Use pagecreate or one of the pagecontainer widget's events instead. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/9st8ytco/1/

Comment: My flipswitches are in a jqm popup. Could this cause a problem?

Comment: Should make no difference: http://jsfiddle.net/9st8ytco/2/  Can you make the fiddle reproduce the issue?

Comment: Maybe I'm not applying JQM the right way? http://apps.opolo.nl/geloofshelden/index.html

Comment: Can't access the site - 403 forbidden

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
* UI Behaviour,
* Toggle switches.
* @param {bool} isOn || isOff
* @access public
*/
function updateUiSwitches( el, isOn ) {

    el.find( 'input[type=checkbox]' ).each(function( index, el ) {

        $( el ).flipswitch().prop( 'checked', ( isOn )? true : false ).flipswitch( 'refresh' );

    });

}

// toggle switch on
updateUiSwitches( $( '#quote' ), true );
```

:) 
Sorry Boet; just bashed it out on notepad for you, it's not tested. . . 
but should do the trick ( or something at least in the desired direction ).

Answer (score 0):

The HTML in question has either been programmatically injected. Or the HTML was hidden, for example, in a tab, so never initialized by jQuery Mobile.

Call this atleast once prior to `refresh()`:

```
$("#quote").enhanceWithin();
```

You can enhance as large a code block as you like:

```
$("#huge-html-content").enhanceWithin();
```